# mvn checkstyle:checkstyle uses wrong configuration when using reporting

Tags: java, maven, checkstyle

Im facing the following problem. I have set up my checkstyle with the following configuration:

```xml
<reporting>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${checkstyle.plugin.version}</version>
            <inherited/>
            <configuration>
                <configLocation>${basedir}/checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
                <includeTestSourceDirectory>true</includeTestSourceDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>
```

This runs fine when I run `mvn site`. However, when I run checkstyle through `mvn checkstyle:checkstyle` in order to get the XML report much more efficiently, the checkstyle plugin fails back to use the default configuration. When I move the plugin to `<build>` the XML is generated properly, but now the checkstyle report is not included in the generated site anymore.

What is the (*current*) way of setting up report plugins as Checkstyle, while perserving the ability to run the plugin separately under the same configuration?

Is it really the preferred way to defined your plugins and configuration twice?

Comment: What version of Checkstyle are you using?

Comment: maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.15. And here I found the unsatisfying answer: https://github.com/sevntu-checkstyle/checkstyle-samples/blob/master/maven-project/pom.xml

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution. Please post it as an answer, too.

Comment: Isn't this a fix rather than a solution? I would personally expect different behaviour? Why can't reporting plugins be ran separately using the right configuration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, apparently you should add the plugin with configuration to both `<build>` and `<reporting>`.